# How does one add an "id" attribute to Html.LabelFor() in ASP.NET MVC2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, html-helper

How would one add an "id" attribute to Html.LabelFor() in ASP.NET MVC2?

This is my label code:

```
<%=Html.LabelFor(x => x.FirstName)%>
```

This is my failed attempt:

```
<%=Html.LabelFor(x => x.FirstName, new { @id = "first-name" } )%>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an helper that should do what you need:

```
public static MvcHtmlString LabelFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, string id)
{
    ModelMetadata meta = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData), 
    string ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression)

    string labelText = metadata.DisplayName ?? metadata.PropertyName ?? htmlFieldName.Split('.').Last();
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(labelText)) {
        return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
    }

    TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("label");
    tag.Attributes.Add("for", html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(htmlFieldName));
    tag.MergeAttribute("id", id);
    tag.SetInnerText(labelText);
    return tag.ToMvcHtmlString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
}
```

a simple modification from the LabelFor helper in the asp.net mvc source.

Answer (score 0):

The LabelFor, TextBoxFor, XXXFor methods automatically add the id based on the name of the property.  I don't think you can override that.  If you want to be able to set the id, you'll need to use the "non-For" methods like Html.TextBox.

Comment: Actually, I don't think that LabelFor adds an id at all -- the id would presumably be applied to the input field that is associated with the label.  I think that you're right that you need to use the non-strongly-typed version to add HTML attributes, though.

Answer (score 0):

How about this extension method

```
public static class LabelExtensions

    {
        public static string Label(this HtmlHelper helper, string target, string id, string text)
        {
            return String.Format("<label for='{0}' id='{1}'>{2}</label>", target,id, text);
        }
    }
```

*Edit*

I think the better way would be to use the tagbuilder similar to [this example](http://www.joeyb.org/blog/2010/01/21/aspnet-mvc-2-htmlhelper-extensions) and use the MergeAttribute function to include the id.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the behavior has changed since MVC2 because, although I'm using Razor and VB.NET, I got this code to work, and it should be about the same with the possible exception of the `@` you put before `id` (I'm now using MVC4):

```
@Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.ItemNumber, New With {.id = "ItemNumberL"})
```

This generated the following HTML:

```
<label for="ItemNumber" id="ItemNumberL">ItemNumber</label>
```